# IBinder between Bound Service and Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

Maybe I'm just tired. However I am struggling to understand just how the IBinder interface works.

A service has a method call onBind(Intent intent) and this passes some form of the IBinder to a binding activity.

Where I am struggling is how to visualize this. Is an IBinder object a pipe between the service and activity, so that an activity can interact directly with the service? Or is an IBinder an object that is passed to the activity that has information from the Service in it (similar to an intent)?

Edit: The idea is for me to be able to call the getSomeData function from the binding activity. Or rather, the idea is to get the mSomeData obect to the activity.

I have the following classes that I am using, and Im trying to figure out the best way to have the activity request data (serializable if needed though I'd rather not) from the service.

```
public class MainService extends Service{

    private CustomBinder mIBinder;
    private SomeDataObject mSomeData;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mIBinder = new CustomBinder();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public CustomBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    // This is auto generated and I havent changed it yet. I am not
    // Experiencing errors as this is not designed to run yet.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    public final SomeDataObject getSomeData(){
        return mSomeData;
    }

    class SomeBinder extends MainEngineBinder{
        // All the Auto Generated Stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: the first case - the client activity can call `transact()` method on the returned binder and the `onTransact()` will be called on the service side

Comment: That's interesting. I'm going to play with it a bit. So what would be the correct way to add methods that return objects in a binder?

Comment: what objects? and what methods? do you mean [AIDL](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) methods? or just raw IBinder without any high level AIDL?

Comment: I suppose I'm not sure how to answer that. I'll edit my post to show a bit of context on what I'm tinkering with. I am not using AIDL at the current time.

Comment: @pskink I have added some code to the post

Comment: so what is `mIBinder` for if it is not used anywhere? it should be returned from `onBind` method, have you read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)?

Comment: Obviously the mIBinder is to be returned in the onBind method, which is exactly what I noted in the method. I am more asking about how the IBinder functions and how the Service to Activity relationship works. If needed I can post the route I take to get the binder into the activity as well but it doesn't have relevance to the question I posed, which is more, if an IBinder is a pipe which links a Service and an Activity, how would I go about making calls from the Activity to the Service and getting the proper information through said pipe

Comment: ok i'm sorry: did not read the comments ;-( the first question: is the service and the clients hosted by the same process (meaning if all the stuff is within the same app)?

Comment: No problems :) Yes they are both hosted in the same application all together. I could go and do some hackish thing like create a class and just share the information between then but I am trying to do it "the right way" and keep data in the relevant objects.

Comment: so follow this: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder, notice the first sentence: `"If your service is used only by the local application and does not need to work across processes"`

Comment: but if you really really want to go low level `IBinder` stuff then for testing simply `return new Binder() {...` from `onBind` method, add some `Log.d` inside `onTransact` method and call `transact()` method inside `ServiceConnection#onServiceConnected` on the activity side - that way you will be allowed to cross process boundaries but it will be much slower too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know how `IBinder` works. Just subclass `Binder` (Not `IBinder`) and add some methods to the `Binder` subclass. These methods can be called from the activity bound to your service.

The easiest way to do this in your case is to have an inner class extend `Binder`, and that inner class will then be able to access methods/fields from your service and return them to the activity. You look like you're working from a similar template as the [Android documentation on bound services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html), so here's the example from the docs - all the binder does in this case is expose a getter for getting the service itself, and a caller can simply call methods *directly on the service*:

```
public class LocalService extends Service {
    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    // Random number generator
    private final Random mGenerator = new Random();

    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocalService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    /** method for clients */
    public int getRandomNumber() {
      return mGenerator.nextInt(100);
    }
}
```

The caller calling bind() will need to cast the `IBinder` to `LocalService.LocalBinder`. In this case, the `IBinder` is neither a pipe nor an intent-like object; it is a normal Java-style interface.

Note that all of this holds true if you are *not* doing IPC. [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) states that in this case (same application, same process) the call is a normal Java call - you can pass objects, references, whatever you like, because everything is in the same process.

Note that IPC, pipes, marshalling, serialisation and the like are all unnecessary (unless you want your service to be called from other apps or if you use multi-process apps). An Android service is not even run in a separate thread unless you start a new thread explicitly, and does not have it's "own" thread or process - all calls made to binders or the service object itself are made in the same thread as the caller.

In your case, the exact example from the Android documentation seems like the best approach.